# Couchbase Cordova - doc_ids | Need to get uuids

Tags: mongodb, cordova, couchbase-lite

I am trying to get the doc_ids in couchbase cordova to be in uuid format.
Currently, any doc that is inserted has `_id`s like - `-AexsV4lbjOoH-AdlN1Fi0W` , `--mpIWIHza6CQEJEHRxPKba` etc.

My setup is of such nature that the _ids need to be uuids as the cordova app will save the local DB as a part of a universal MongoDB on the server.
(So the DB on the server will have multiple local DBs stored). Hence, I need the _ids to be uuids

I did a quick research into how to create uuids in JS and found quite a few answers like -

```
/**
 * Fast UUID generator, RFC4122 version 4 compliant.
 * @author Jeff Ward (jcward.com).
 * @license MIT license
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript/21963136#21963136
 **/
var UUID = (function() {
  var self = {};
  var lut = []; for (var i=0; i<256; i++) { lut[i] = (i<16?'0':'')+(i).toString(16); }
  self.generate = function() {
    var d0 = Math.random()*0xffffffff|0;
    var d1 = Math.random()*0xffffffff|0;
    var d2 = Math.random()*0xffffffff|0;
    var d3 = Math.random()*0xffffffff|0;
    return lut[d0&0xff]+lut[d0>>8&0xff]+lut[d0>>16&0xff]+lut[d0>>24&0xff]+'-'+
      lut[d1&0xff]+lut[d1>>8&0xff]+'-'+lut[d1>>16&0x0f|0x40]+lut[d1>>24&0xff]+'-'+
      lut[d2&0x3f|0x80]+lut[d2>>8&0xff]+'-'+lut[d2>>16&0xff]+lut[d2>>24&0xff]+
      lut[d3&0xff]+lut[d3>>8&0xff]+lut[d3>>16&0xff]+lut[d3>>24&0xff];
  }
  return self;
})();
```

which generates uuids like `d6414228-b07c-4bd2-9aa3-d1df8b548de6`
So my question is - is there a direct way inside couchbase phonegap plugin to achieve this directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing a document to Couchbase Lite, you can either let the database pick a random ID (it will be unique) or specify one.

You can send a POST request to have the database generate the document ID.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -vX POST 'http://localhost:5984/app' \
     -d '{"name": "john"}'

{"id":"-UwALc1GlcAcG60uag1oMf1","rev":"1-10dc5637dc2ccb55e007440cca73a415","ok":true}
```

Or a PUT request to specify one.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -vX PUT 'http://localhost:5984/app/john' \
     -d '{"name": "john"}'

{"id":"john","rev":"1-10dc5637dc2ccb55e007440cca73a415","ok":true}
```

Note that from then on you must specify the revision number of the current revision to save updates on the document.

```bash
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -vX PUT 'http://localhost:5984/app/john?rev=1-10dc5637dc2ccb55e007440cca73a415' \
     -d '{"name": "johnny"}'
```

Comment: Ahmm.. so how do I tell couchbase to generate uuids instead of "random id"?

Comment: You don't, but you can put your generated uuid in instead of "john" in the example above.

Comment: So the only way is to generate custom ids?

Comment: Yes.  Couchbase is currently designed to use either its own id generation scheme, or have you control ids directly.

Comment: @Hod Thanks. Guess will have to go and create uuids then!